# How to typecheck arguments to then()

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In the function below the Promise resolves to `1`, and thus `typeof astring === 'number'`. However, with `strictFunctionTypes` I don't get the warning that `number` conflicts with `astring: string`, instead I see `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'`.

How can I improve my typechecking for functions provided to `then()`?

```
function test(): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
  })
  .then((astring: string) => {
    return 'string';
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the type parameter to `Promise`, Typescript will not infer based on the usage of `resolve` that the return type of the promise will be `number`:

```
function test(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(1);
    })
    .then((nr: number) => {
        return 'string';
    })
}

//error
function test2(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(1);
    })
    .then((nr: string) => {
        return 'string';
    })
}
```